# Test if a string is a Java variable identifier: (a-z,A-Z,_,$) followed by (a-z,A-Z,0-9,_,$)

Tags: java, testing, variables, expression, identifier

I need to determine if a string is a variable identifier.

i.e. (a-z,A-Z,*,$) followed by (a-z,A-Z,0-9,*,$)

I know I can do it with a manually configured reg exp, but there must be a more compact, built in function I can use.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the methods `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart()` and `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart()` but I don't think the solution will be more compact.

EDIT: I decided to search and found this in Codemodel: http://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JJavaName.html

Comment: I suppose I could tuck it all away in a helper method, but yes, I'm hoping for a built in compact solution.